# Fetching pdf pages as bitmap with selectable text/content

Tags: android

I have searched a lot of libraries but can't find any exact solution for this. Actually i am working on an app in which i have to fetch pages (or content) as bitmap from pdf but also have to add the highlight property on content of pdf. I tried iText library, its good in fetching text and images from pdf. But it fetch text and images separately, not as exactly same as it is in pdf itself. I saw an app "Moon+Reader App". This app also fetch pdfs from our device an open them as shown in screenshot. Its a bitmaop image of a pdf page with selectable text. Is there any library which can do this, or if any other methodology is used then please help me by answer.  [image: Screenshot]

Comment: "Its a bitmaop image of a pdf page with selectable text" -- how have you proven that this is a bitmap?

Comment: @CommonsWare I think this is a bitmap because looking of page is exactly the same as in original  pdf

Comment: @CommonsWare Sir please help me, i want to open a pdf in my application without adobe reader. There is a class PdfRenderer but it is only for API level 21 or above

Comment: "I think this is a bitmap because looking of page is exactly the same as in original pdf" -- any PDF viewer should have the page "exactly the same as in original pdf". Text in bitmaps is not selectable. Hence, AFAIK, what you are seeking is impossible.

Comment: @CommonsWare So how can I create a pdf reader.

Comment: The simple solution is to use [a PDF rendering library](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare But sir  it is only for API level 21 or above. Am i right ?

Comment: My previous comment contains a hyperlink to [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html). There, I cite three possible approaches. One (`PdfRenderer`) requires API Level 21. One (`PDF.js`) requires API Level 19. One (`pdfium`) works back to at least API Level 16 and possibly older than that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155026/discussion-between-itava-and-commonsware).